# UINavigation with UITabbar not working

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I'm trying to change views within an app I am editing the code for. But the navigation bar doesn't seem to update in specific instances when presenting a new viewcontroller. Right now the behavior looks like this:
I navigate to a tableviewcontroller by clicking on a tab in the tabbar,
then I navigate to a viewcontroller from this tableviewcontroller using:

```
 settingsController = [SettingsController create];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController: settingsController animated: YES];
```

which I believe calls this code:

```
+(id)create
{
    SettingsController*settings = [[SettingsController alloc] init];
    NSBundle*bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass: [SettingsController class]];
    [bundle loadNibNamed: @"SettingsController" owner: settings options: NULL];
    settings.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 411);

    settings.title = @"Settings";

    return settings;
}
```

Then from there I navigate to another view controller using:

```
SearchViewController*searchView;
searchView = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchView" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentViewController:searchView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and this is where the behavior starts getting buggy, the navigation bar doesnt update to the change in the view controller. I didn't write this code but it has been giving me a headache trying to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a navigationController then you shouldn't call

`[self presentViewController:searchView animated:YES completion:nil];`.

You should use

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:searchView animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

Also, it would be better to use the standard in-built function to initialize a new view controller.

```
SettingsController*settings = [[SettingsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:settings animated:YES];
```

and then use the default method in the view controller.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = @"Settings";
    //other view changes.
}
 return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example for the way of initializing tabbarcontroller with navigation controller

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2,*viewController3;
viewController1 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
viewController2 = [[FormStatusViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FormStatusViewController" bundle:nil];
viewController3 = [[DocumentsViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
UINavigationController *nav1 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
UINavigationController *nav2 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];


nav.navigationBarHidden=YES;
nav1.navigationBarHidden=YES;
nav2.navigationBarHidden=YES;


NSArray *viewsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nav,nav1,nav2, nil];
self.formTabBar= [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.formTabBar setViewControllers:viewsArray];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.formTabBar.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];


tabBarItem1.title = @"FORM";
tabBarItem2.title = @"STATUS";
tabBarItem3.title = @"DOCUMENTS";

UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bg.png"]
                          resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7) {
    [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"form.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"form_h.png"]];
    [tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_h.png"]];
    [tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"documents.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"documents_h.png"]];
} else {
    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"form_h.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"form.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

    tabBarItem2.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_h.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem2.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"status.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

    tabBarItem3.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"documents_h.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem3.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"documents.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];


}
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_select_indicator.png"]];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = self.formTabBar;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Now in your view controller suppose the firstviewcontroller in first tab you want to navigate to another view controller in that tab then use below code

```
SearchViewcontroller *searchView =[[SearchViewcontroller alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:searchView animated:YES];
```